# Sum up values with thousand separator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got stuck in sum up with thousand separators. When I set a value in the input box only the first digit group sums up in the result box. How to sum up the whole value properly if there is a thousand separator?
Thanks in advance

```js
$("input").change(function () {   

  var c = parseInt($("input[name=cp]").val()),
  a = parseInt($("input[name=ae]").val()),
  d = parseInt($("input[name=d]").val()),
  cs = parseInt ($("input[name=cs]").val());

  var result = ( ( c + a ) - d + cs );

  $("#r").val( result );

}); // end change

$("input[name=cp]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on cp

$("input[name=ae]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on ae

$("input[name=d]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on d

                            
$("input[name=cs]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on cs
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"   name="cp" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="ae" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" name="d" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="cs" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" id="r">
```

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: How to sum up the whole value?

Comment: Offtopic: `this.value = ` on `keyup` is *horrific* UX!  Enter "134", oh should be "1234" - press *left cursor* - cursor moves to end continuously - can't edit the damn text.

Comment: @freedomn-m, thank you for the precise review. Backspace and Delete keyboard could figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[praseInt: Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description)

> If [praseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified *radix*, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. [praseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

You have to replace the spaces from the values before using [praseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var c = parseInt($("input[name=cp]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
a = parseInt($("input[name=ae]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
d = parseInt($("input[name=d]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
cs = parseInt ($("input[name=cs]").val().replace(/ /g,''));
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$("input").change(function () {   
  var c = parseInt($("input[name=cp]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
  a = parseInt($("input[name=ae]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
  d = parseInt($("input[name=d]").val().replace(/ /g,'')),
  cs = parseInt ($("input[name=cs]").val().replace(/ /g,''));
  var result = ( ( c + a ) - d + cs );

  $("#r").val( result );
}); // end change

$("input[name=cp]").on("keyup", function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");                     
}); // end on cp

$("input[name=ae]").on("keyup", function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on ae

$("input[name=d]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on d

                            
$("input[name=cs]").on("keyup", function () {

  this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
  var number = this.value;
  this.value = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

}); // end on cs
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"   name="cp" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="ae" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" name="d" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="cs" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" id="r">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValue(val) {
  return parseInt(val.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''));
}

$("input").change(function () {
  var c = getValue($("input[name=cp]").val()),
  a = getValue($("input[name=ae]").val()),
  d = getValue($("input[name=d]").val()),
  cs = getValue ($("input[name=cs]").val());
  var result = String( ( c + a ) - d + cs ).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
  $("#r").val( result );

}); // end change

$("input[name=cp], input[name=ae], input[name=d], input[name=cs]").on("keyup", function () {
  this.value = String(getValue(this.value)).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}); // end on all
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"   name="cp" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="ae" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" name="d" value="0" maxlength="8" >
<input type="text" name="cs" value="0" maxlength="7" >
<input type="text" id="r">
```

what about this one?